# How to let my android application can only installed on an device which has a screen bigger than 480x800px?

Tags: android, screen

My android application can't run well on small screens. When I design the activities, I assume it only run on screen bigger than (or equal to) `480px` x `800px`. (Yes, I used `px` not `dp`).

Is there any way to configure the application to have this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480" 

/>
```

put this in your manifest

Comment: `requiresSmallestWidthDp`... Does it require `dp`? But my width is `480px`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to configure the application to have this limit?

Not really. The answer from heLL0 will have that net effect, in all likelihood. However, it is really saying "only allow this on devices that are 5" diagonal and larger, with a smallest dimension of 480dp".

This will eliminate some devices that are bigger than 480x800, specifically ones whose smallest dimension is between 480px and 480dp. You could fix this by eliminating the `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` from heLL0's answer.

It would also allow devices that are smaller than 480x800, if they happen to have a screen size bigger than 5". I am not aware of any such devices existing, but you never know what may come about in the future.